Invalid app start data: app not launched in foreground or app start took too long (>60s)
I'm trying to build a Flutter application. Once I configured the flutter_sentry package I started to see these logs when I start the application

W/Sentry  ( 7120): Invalid app start data: app not launched in foreground or app start took too long (>60s)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:431)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:272)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at io.sentry.flutter.SentryFlutterPlugin.fetchNativeAppStart(SentryFlutterPlugin.kt:229)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at io.sentry.flutter.SentryFlutterPlugin.onMethodCall(SentryFlutterPlugin.kt:74)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7924)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#sentry_flutter( 7120):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)


E/DartMessenger( 7120): Uncaught exception in binary message listener
E/DartMessenger( 7120): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:431)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:287)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7924)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/DartMessenger( 7120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
D/EGL_emulation( 7120): app_time_stats: avg=1.61ms min=0.59ms max=21.30ms count=32

I'm new to mobile applications and don't know how to fix this.
This is how I configured Sentry
Future<void> main() async {
  await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) {
      options.dsn =
          '<sentry_dns>';
      // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of transactions for tracing.
      // We recommend adjusting this value in production.
      options.tracesSampleRate = 1.0;
      // The sampling rate for profiling is relative to tracesSampleRate
      // Setting to 1.0 will profile 100% of sampled transactions:
      options.profilesSampleRate = 1.0;
    },
    appRunner: () =>
        runApp(MultiProvider(providers: localProviders, child: const MyApp())),
  );
}

Any help will be appreciated.

Does this only happen for your Android variant? Or does this happen for iOS as well?

I'm only running Android for now
